# SP2013 Restore inheritance on document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, permissions, security, inheritance

Restoring Inheritance on a document library would break unique permissions on childs ?

I have a site XX, inside, a Document Library A, with Folders A1, A2 and A3.

A1, A2 and A3 have unique permissions.
We just broke inheritance on A (from XX).

If we enable again inheritance on A (to get permissions from XX), it would apply inheritance on A1 A2 and A3 ? Or we would keep these unique permissions ?

Thanks in advance
Nico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reestabilish the inheritance, the folder with broken inheritance will keep the broken inheritance. So, it doesn't break unique permissions on children.

Anyway, you can try it yourself simply creating a new test library and setting and breaking inheritance.

I tried it my self too...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As it's a production environment, and I didn't do the modification myself, I came to ask here to be sure of the answer.
Lemme know what you try give, I'll try to find a test env. :)

Comment: Just tried. It works. It does not modify inheritance (or not) of children